# Simple TOC with itextsharp

Tags: c#, itext

I have a website where I am displaying pdf with itextsharp in telerik radwindow. I am succeeded with displaying pdf on telerik radwindow popup. 
 Now, I have page name and their order and need rearrange to display TOC like below with itextsharp

[image]

Comment: What you tried so far? Also what exactly is your question? And what do you use to display stuff? Is this on a website, inside a WinForms application, or is it WPF or are you trying to write to a text document... ?

Comment: Same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55372460/text-alignment-issue-with-string-padding-when-generating-pdf

Comment: This is not a valid question. Showing a picture of something and saying "I want this", is not a question. I recommend reading [ask] and [mcve] in order to get the basic of asking on StackOverflow.

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse yes it is same question. But here I am asking with itexsharp. and in another question I am trying to do it with padding(padright/padleft) of c#. I am appreciate team if they help me either one way. And if it is not a valid question then don't worry we have lots of resources where anyone can understood this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by creating a *chunk separator* (cf. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27056092/1729265)) with a `tabPosition` (to make the page numbers left aligned as you show in your image).

```
using (FileStream output = new FileStream(@"simpleToc.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
using (Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4))
{
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);
    document.Open();

    Chunk leader = new Chunk(new DottedLineSeparator(), 400);

    Paragraph p = new Paragraph("Terms and Conditions");
    p.Add(leader);
    p.Add("4");
    document.Add(p);

    p = new Paragraph("Dental");
    p.Add(leader);
    p.Add("6");
    document.Add(p);

    p = new Paragraph("Vision");
    p.Add(leader);
    p.Add("7");
    document.Add(p);

    p = new Paragraph("Neighborhood Pharmacy");
    p.Add(leader);
    p.Add("8");
    document.Add(p);

    p = new Paragraph("Teladoc");
    p.Add(leader);
    p.Add("9");
    document.Add(p);

    p = new Paragraph("Retail Health Clinics");
    p.Add(leader);
    p.Add("11");
    document.Add(p);

    p = new Paragraph("Counseling Services");
    p.Add(leader);
    p.Add("12");
    document.Add(p);

    p = new Paragraph("Medical Bill Saver\u2122");
    p.Add(leader);
    p.Add("13");
    document.Add(p);

    p = new Paragraph("Vitamins");
    p.Add(leader);
    p.Add("14");
    document.Add(p);
}
```

The result looks like this

[image: Screen Shot]

---

As you called the library "iTextSharp" and only used the [[iText]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/itext/info) tag, I assume you are using iText 5.x, not 7.x. The code above has been tested using the current 5.5.14-SNAPSHOT development version.

---

The `Chunk` constructor used above is marked **Obsolete**:

```
/**
* Creates a tab Chunk.
* Note that separator chunks can't be used in combination with tab chunks!
* @param   separator   the drawInterface to use to draw the tab.
* @param   tabPosition an X coordinate that will be used as start position for the next Chunk.
* @since   2.1.2
*/
[Obsolete]
public Chunk(IDrawInterface separator, float tabPosition) : this(separator, tabPosition, false)
```

But as the old iText 5.x version as a whole is in maintenance mode, there is no need to fear that it will be dropped from the assembly during further development.